# Long press in UiAutomation

Tags: android, ui-automation

I am working on Uiautomation for android using eclipse in the moto X device android 4.4 kitkat.I am doing automation to connect to wifi with a static IP and using OPEN security. To set security I need to do long press on the AP name, how can I do long press with Uiautomation. I had tried with UiObject.longClick() but its not doing long press and that UiObject's long-clickable is set to FALSE. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use swipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, int steps) to perform a long click for the time you wish. The last parameter, steps, determines the time. For 100 steps, the swipe will take about 1/2 of a second to complete. The greater the value of steps, the longer the duration of the press.
Example:

```
UiObject connect = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.LinearLayout").instance(6));
Rect rectButton = connect.getBounds();
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance();
device.swipe(rectButton.centerX(), rectButton.centerY(), rectButton.centerX(), rectButton.centerY(), 200);
```

Here, connect is the UiObject which I am performing a long click on.