# Long press on power button by UiAutomator

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator

How achieve long press on power button (KeyEvent 26 ) to get a power menu by UiAutomator ?

Comment: This [long press example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237332/long-press-in-uiautomation) might give you some ideas -

Comment: The power button is a hard button , in your example there a  long pressing of virtual button on the Ui device.

Answer (score 0):

Below,it is long press home button solution,and it works.Maybe you can attempt to use power KeyCode instead of mDevice.pressHome().

```
public void longPressHome(){
    long timeout = Configurator.getInstance().getActionAcknowledgmentTimeout();
    Configurator.getInstance().setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(0);
    mDevice.pressHome();
    mDevice.pressHome();
    Configurator.getInstance().setActionAcknowledgmentTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using reflection:

```
Class<?> clazz = mDevice.getClass();
Method getUiAutomation = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getUiAutomation");
getUiAutomation.setAccessible(true);

((UiAutomation) getUiAutomation.invoke(mDevice)).performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
```

Answer (score -1):

To tackle this-
Please try this tool.[Android Record N Play](https://github.com/rils/ARP/wiki) . Record your power button long press. And run with the tool. Or push the xxx.mes file to phone and run `adb shell sh xxx.mes` to run separately.
I tested on Galaxy s6, it works fine. if you face any problem please comment here. I can fix the issue.

you can call the `adb shell sh` comamnd from uiautomator.